# Unable to proxy React over to api localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have added the following in my `package.json`

```
  "proxy": "https://localhost:44318/"
```

and here is my api localhost `https://localhost:44318/`
but when i `npm start`and try to call the api action `/api/sampledata` i get the action wont get called and i get `404 not found` in network header of my browser. the end point wont be called as i have a breakpoint on it and i'll know if it gets triggred. ive tried many methods online. does anyone have an experience with this? any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it is https? it should be http - you must not have ssl certificate if its https. This could be one reason for  404 since the path doesnt get matched and its not able to find . Also start your sever aswell for the backed (if yes then ignore)

Comment: Please refer this: https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347

Comment: @AyushiKeshri i tried that too didnt work